# How to add more choices to existing choice Field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Here's my setup:

I have a list with this Field in it (created from vs2010):

```
ID="{854D15F6-C70F-4C79-AB59-40C8786EF825}"
 Name="fooSelector"
 Type="Choice"
 Sealed="TRUE"
 Required="TRUE"
 DisplayName="Fruits">
  <CHOICES>
   <CHOICE>Apple</CHOICE>
   <CHOICE>Cherry</CHOICE>
   <CHOICE>Both</CHOICE>
  </CHOICES>
</Field>
```

I want to add more choices to this Field. 
I tried with two samples found on the web using powershell...
A)

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb http://intranet/foo

$spList = $spWeb.Lists["Dynamics-Nav List"]
$choices =  New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
 "Fish",
 "Melon"  | ForEach-Object { $choices.Add($_) | Out-Null }

$spList.Fields.Add("Fruits",
 [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Choice,
 $false,
 $false,
 $choices) 
$spList.Fields[“Fruits”].Update()
```

B)

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://intranet/foo
$l = $w.Lists["Dynamics-Nav List"]
$uf = $l.Fields["Fruits"]
$uf.Choices
$uf.Choices.Add("Fish");
$uf.update()
$l.update();
```

Both run fine without error, afterwards the $uf.Choices shows the just added "Fish" choice, but neither changes are saved.

What am i doing wrong?

Best wishes,
 Armin

Answer (score 1):

try with powershell

```
$suryafield = "<Field Type='Choice' DisplayName='Surya' Required='TRUE' Format='Dropdown' Group='Custom Columns'
      FillInChoice='FALSE' StaticName='Surya' Name='Surya'>
            <CHOICES>
                <CHOICE>YES</CHOICE>
                <CHOICE>NO</CHOICE>
            </CHOICES>
           </Field>"
      $web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($suryafield)
```

for more info see this post
http://suryapulipati.blogspot.com/2013/08/create-sharepoint-choice-field-site.html

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code From Code Behind :**

```
string newField = string.Concat("<Field Type='Choice' DisplayName='",
                    "FieldName", "' Name='", "FieldName", "' ",
                    "Format='Dropdown' Required='TRUE' Indexed='TRUE'><CHOICES>",
                    "<CHOICE>1</CHOICE>",
                    "<CHOICE>2</CHOICE>",
                    "<CHOICE>3</CHOICE>",
                    "</CHOICES><Default>1</Default>",
                    "<Description> Status.",
                    "</Description></Field>");

    list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(newField, true,SPAddFieldOptions.AddFieldToDefaultView);
    Web.Update();
```